# Python Importing object that originates in one module from a different module into a third module

Tags: python, import

I was reading the sourcode for a python project and came across the following line:

```
from couchexport.export import Format
```

(source: https://github.com/wbnigeria/couchexport/blob/master/couchexport/views.py#L1 )

I went over to `couchexport/export.py` to see what `Format` was (Class? Dict? something else?).  Unfortunately `Format` isn't in that file.  `export.py` does however import a `Format` from couchexport.models where there *is* a `Format` class (source: https://github.com/wbnigeria/couchexport/blob/master/couchexport/models.py#L11).

When I open up the original file in my IDE and have it look up the declaration, in line I mentioned at the start of this question, it leads directly to models.py.

What's going on?  How can an import from one file (`export.py`) actually be an import from another file (`models.py`) without being explicitly stated?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If module `a` does a `from b import Foo`, then `Foo` is a member of `a` afterwards and accessible as `a.Foo`. It's only consequent that you can now import it too using `from a import Foo`.

This is commonly used if you have a large library distributed across multiple files and you want them to be accessible from a single location. Let's say you have a package `foo` with the following layout:

```
foo/
    a.py
    b.py
    c.py
    __init__.py
```

`a.py`, `b.py`, `c.py`, define the classes `A`, `B` and `C`, respectively.

If you wanted to use those classes, you'd normally have to write

```
from foo.a import A
from foo.b import B
from foo.c import C
```

This has at least two problems:

1. Much code (three lines) is needed for this simple import
2. The library author can now no longer change the file/class association afterwards, because that would break existing code.

So normally you just put the following in the `__init__.py`:

```
from a import A
from b import B
from c import C
```

Now you put all the pieces together in a single place and all of the classes are accessible with one import:

```
from foo import A,B,C
```

Comment: I'm not sure what problem #1 is saying.

Comment: I thought it might be an untranslated idiom but since `type` means something in Python too I wasn't sure.  :^)